# Use of term "simplify answer"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm not sure if this question will be able to be answered over here, but it is a question about the use of the phrase: "simplify your answer."
I am working on linear algebra. I have many questions asking me to find a matrix or to diagonalize a matrix, etc. The question will usually ask me to simplify my answer. What they mean is to multiply my answer by some scalar to ensure that all numbers are whole numbers. I know this does not change my answer in any significant way, but is this the normal definition of this term?

Comment: For me, it means being the form of easiest to read and understand. Obviously this is subjective, and depend on context. For example $xy(x+y)=x^2y+xy^2$, both can be considered "simplified". It's usually dependent on specific scenario. In your example of matrix, if the denominators are co-prime, then the form your book described isn't necessarily simple.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do with the answer. A polynomial written as $x^3 - 6 x^2 + 11 x - 6$ could be considered "in simplest form" for some operations (eg, finding its derivative), but for finding roots it is much more simple to have it written in factored form $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$.

Comment: @Burt Can you give a precise example ?